# Blocks in Obj-C for performSelector: onThread:?

Tags: objective-c, ios

While it wouldn't be hard to spin up my own method for this, it wouldn't be as efficient as

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector onThread:(NSThread *)thr withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;
```

**is there a built-in method to do this with blocks?**

If not, is there a way I can avoid creating an object, putting the block on it, and passing it to a selector method? I also wonder if there would be problems with data accessed within the block...

Comment: Are you specifically asking how to run a block on a given thread, or just on a non-main thread?

Comment: Thanks @Brad Larson. It has to be a specific thread, because it's the one my AsyncSocket works on.

Comment: @Yar: Is there a reason you're not using GCDAsyncSocket? It's part of the [project](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) itself and is implemented using blocks, let alone having great support for them. It also has a lot of other very useful features (greater SSL support) etc. that you might find useful.

Comment: @Sedate Allen, sorry, I missed this comment. 1) I stripped out all of my "run AsyncSocket" on another thread because it turned out not to be a bottleneck and 2) I am using `AsyncSocket` but this http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/wiki/Reference_GCDAsyncSocket does look interesting. I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: @Sedate Allen, just an update, this turned out to be totally irrelevant and in fact the problems were on the other side of the socket (also written by me :)... all is well now, and I'm letting Async Socket handles the threads as it needs to.

Comment: @Yar: Sounds good, the important thing is that the problem was solved! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blocks equivalent to the `performSelector:` method is `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` — you just need to get a reference to that thread's `CFRunLoop`.

Have a look at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001441-CH201-SW7) for the function and note the caveat in the discussion — you'll probably want to call `CFRunLoopWakeUp` afterwards so the block is executed right away.

Comment: Man, that's terse! +1 because I found all the stuff you're talking about.

Comment: I haven't had time to implement this, so I'll put my notes here: I have an `NSThread` and a block. I get a `CFRunLoopRef` by calling `CFRunLoopGetCurrent` and then I call `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` using the `CFRunLoopRef` and a constant from here `kCFRunLoopCommonModes`...

`This method enqueues the block only and does not automatically wake up the specified run loop. Therefore, execution of the block occurs the next time the run loop wakes up to handle another input source. If you want the work performed right away, you must explicitly wake up that thread using the CFRunLoopWakeUp function.`

Answer (score 5):

Since blocks are implemented as objective-c objects, you could cast one to `id` and pass it to `performSelector:...` methods. To do what you want, you could define a category on NSObject which accepts and calls the block. Here is an example. It uses an NSArray as the argument so that you can pass an indeterminate number of arguments, and they will be passed to the block in an array.

```
typedef void (^PerformableBlock)(NSArray *arguments);
@implementation NSObject (PerformBlocks)
- (void)performBlockWithArray:(NSArray *)blockAndArguments {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    PerformableBlock theBlock = (PerformableBlock)[blockAndArguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *blockArgs = [arguments subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){1,[arguments count] - 1}];
    theBlock(blockArgs);
    [pool release];
}
@end
```

You would then call this using code similar to this:

```
PerformableBlock myBlock = ^(NSArray *args) {
    NSLog(@"%@",args);
};
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)myBlock, arg1, arg2, nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(performBlockWithArray:) onThread:theThread withObject:array waithUntilDone:YES];
```

As mentioned by Nick in the comments, a block which uses local variables will be created on the stack. This means that you need to use `[[myBlock copy] autorelease]` when adding it to the array if you choose not to wait until it is done, or it could be deallocated before it is called.

Comment: @Yar Yes it should, thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix it in the post.

Comment: Great answer. A little hacky, but compared to messing with `CFRunLoopPerformBlock` it might be preferable: not messing with new concepts does have advantages. Though... I'll have to get the CFRunLoopPerformBlock stuff working anyway... :)

Comment: Remember that block objects start off on the stack until they get sent a `copy` message, so something like `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[myBlock copy] autorelease], arg1, arg2, nil];` would usually be necessary. It probably doesn't matter here, because you have `waitUntilDone:YES`, but it's something that can bite you in other cases.

Comment: @Nick Good point. It also depends on the block, as a block which doesn't use any variables from its environment will be created globally instead of on the stack, but I will add a note to my answer.

Comment: Great comment, @Nick Hutchinson. Why is it NECESSARY to copy them? Because otherwise you have race conditions for your stack variables (without `waitUntilDone`)?

Comment: @Yar I presume it's because if waitUntilDone is set to NO then then any objects passed in the array might be deallocated before being used.